# Upgrade EC2 Instance to a larger SPOT Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm currently configuring my EC2 instance on the free t1.micro to make sure my simulations will running properly.  After I'm done with the config stage, I want to upgrade my EC2 instance to a much larger **SPOT** instance.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8243307/1583516) shows exactly how to upgrade an instance, but I think the new instance will be an on-demand instance.  How can I upgrade to a larger **spot** instance?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change an on-demand instance to a spot instance. You'll need to create an AMI from the current instance and then launch a new spot instance using the AMI.